# MAMP could not find folder

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, mamp

I’ve been using MAMP for many years and after I created a clean install of my Mac. So I installed MAMP again. But this time it will not work.

I installed the program and put my files in htdocs. Started the program and started the server and Apache and MySQL is green. MAMP start page opens and everything works. When I navigate to `http://localhost:8888` then the root folder comes up and list existing files & folders.

When I then try to navigate to my test site redirected me to `http://www.localhost:8888` and get the message that the page cannot be found.

What can I do about this?

MAMP start page works fine.

Apache & MySQL works fine (Green lights).

MAMP loads `htdocs` and listing it but can not navigate to further in to the folders in htdocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your .htaccess file needs changing, as you've got a re-write code in there that will take whatever is in the URL field, and add www. infront of it.

This is usually used in live environments to redirect someone going to http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com

What does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: Of course! So simple, sometimes requires a different point of view to find errors :) Thank You!